# Help! Вопрос к знатокам про random

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа

В питоне совсем не давно, но возникла идея создать скрипт для генерации hexов 64 символа с использованием модуля random
для python3.x

Суть работы заключается в следующем:
Запускаем скрипт и он генерирует случайные значения от low до high, где- то между диапазоном low и high нужно найти определенный hex, пусть это будет 
check, если найдет сохранит. 
Как увеличить скорость генерации, чтобы процесс поиска был на много быстрее, чем по дефольту. При запуске скрипта нагрузки почти нету, остальные ядра простаивают.

Например возьмем маленький диапазон.

```
import random

low  = 0xa10000000000000000000000000000000000000cdeeeeeeeeeeeeffffffff000
high = 0xa10000000000000000000000000000000000000cdeeeeeeeeeeeefffffffffff
check ="a10000000000000000000000000000000000000cdeeeeeeeeeeeeffffffff258"
while True:
    ran = random.randrange(low,high,1)
    hex = "%064x" % ran
    hex = hex[:64]
    print("hex:",hex)

    if check in hex:
        print("Found!",check)
        s1 = hex
        f=open("found.txt","a")
        f.write("hex: " + s1 + "\n\n") 
        f.close()
```

Comment: Зачем искать уже известный check?

Comment: Вот он check - бери его и передавай, зачем искать уже найденное? Или ты неправильно объяснил задачу или сам не знаешь, что нужно.

Comment: Еще раз: зачем тебе искать уже известное значение чтобы передать его дальше? Ты его уже нашел. Вон оно записано. Диапазон тут вообще не имеет значения. Ищу я 3 среди 100 чисел или среди 100500 - без разницы. Я уже нашел 3 и искать вообще не надо.

Comment: Т.к. суть задачи вообще неясна, то и непонятно, что тут нужно ускорять.

Comment: Всё ещё непонятно, зачем пытаться искать значение, которое и так изначально известно.

Comment: На мой неискушенный взгляд это не та задача, которой требуется работа i9 с 18-тью ядрами. Если конечно это не частная подзадача более общей по генерации криптовалют.

Comment: @BTCMAKER можно математически на бумаге с ручкой доказать, что столкновения будут. Зачем для этого запускать какой-то код?

Comment: ну тогда распараллеливание, конечно, нужно. Только в python еще пока нет продвинутых методов ассинхронного программирования. Код желательно писать на объектном c.

Comment: @BTCMAKER зачем его искать, если столкновение уже заранее найдено и находится в переменной `check`? вы можете сразу записать его в файл `found.txt` и больше ничего не делать.

Comment: Коллеги, а где в задаче вы вообще увидели, что ведется поиск в массиве? Между диапазонами? Посмотрите код -  random.randrange(low,high,1) - тривиальная генерация единственного числа  и последующая проверка его на совпадение с "задуманным". Все.

Comment: Как вы собираетесь искать в hex данные, которые вам неизвестно как выглядят hex?

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я понял из дискуссии и из приведенного скрипта, делается следующее:

1. C помощью функции из библиотеки генерируется integer-число из некоторого диапазона ran.
2. Это число переводится в строку(строковую переменную!) hex.
3. Выполняется проверка вхождения подстроки check в строку hex.

Если длина подстроки и строки совпадают, то по сути вы написали игру "угадай задуманное число".

Теперь вопрос - что вы хотите ускорить? Генерацию случайного числа? Ну так пишите свой, если умеете. Проверку вхождения подстроки в строку? Тут вообще тривиальный алгоритм и не думаю,что его даже теоретически можно улучшить.

При чем тут распараллеливание?  Что именно и зачем вы хотите в данной задаче параллелить? 
Ваш код написан в последовательности "сгенерировали-проверили-записали".  Вы собираетесь параллельно выполнять  такие циклы - это можно  (кроме записи в файл разумеется), но что это даст? Только добавит накладных расходов на синхронизацию.

В общем, без разумной постановки задачи - не удивительно, что вас никто не может понять.